# Record a Mobile application to create a JMeter script

Tags: jmeter, nox

We have a mobile application and recently deployed a new version with updated features. We are creating new JMeter scripts by recording the login, add credit card etc., features using nox recorder. We find a strange issue that a field 'State' which has LOV is not getting displayed with its full list. Once we click state field, it should allow us to choose the state name from the dropdown list. But clicking on this field is not showing the list. Not sure where it is going wrong. Any workaround, tips please would help us. Thanks in advance.

Record mobile application with nox mobile recorder.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We are still in recording phase. Once it is done successfully, we can finetune the JMeter code. Our issue is drop down list is not working while recording for the mobile application. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

nox recorder seems to be a video recording software, it won't help you in creating a JMeter test script.

JMeter can record mobile traffic given its [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTPS)

In case of HTTPS you will need to install JMeter's certificate onto the mobile device like it's described in "HTTPS recording and certificates" section of [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) JMeter User Manual entry.

Additionally

- for iOS you will need to [enable full trust](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477) for JMeter certificate
- for Android you will need to amend your application [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) like it's described in [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354685999889-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording) guide